# Show pictures after read with tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm building a project where I use the tkinter library. Purpose: Create with a tkinter window, where initially there are two buttons 'open 1' and 'open 2', when any image is opened, the selected image is displayed.

I added my existing code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

start = tk.Tk()
start.title("Start")
start.geometry("700x400")

filenames = ["", ""]

def bu_1():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open 1.", filetypes=(("PNG", "*.png"), ("JPG", "*.jpg")))
    filenames[0] = file
    #code to show picture
def bu_2():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open 1.", filetypes=(("PNG", "*.png"), ("JPG", "*.jpg")))
    filenames[1] = file
#code to show picture


open_1 = tk.Button(start, text="Open 1.", padx=10, pady=5, command=bu_1) 
open_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 30)
open_2 = tk.Button(start, text="Open 2.", padx=10, pady=5, command=bu_2) 
open_2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 70)

start.mainloop()
```

[image: Here's a picture to understand what I want to get.]

But i do not know how I can do that. Maybe someone could help?

Comment: Look into the `pillow` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer could be found:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loading-images-in-tkinter-using-pil/

```
def open_img():
    # Select the Imagename  from a folder
    x = openfilename()
 
    # opens the image
    img = Image.open(x)
     
    # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
 
    # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
  
    # create a label
    panel = Label(root, image = img)
     
    # set the image as img
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(row = 2)
```